# Wrapping text into new line

Tags: javascript, css, json

I've been trying to wrap up long texts from a JSON file but i couldn't find a way around it. it keeps displaying as multiple fields of a single response as seen in the image below. I've tried word-break, overflow-wrap but none worked... please help me

[image: IMAGE SHOWING MULTIPLE FIELD OF A SINGLE RESPONSE]

This is my script:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("form").on("submit", function (event) {
    var rawText = $("#text").val();
    var userHtml =
      '<p class="received-msg-inbox"><span class="received-msg-inbox-p">' +
      rawText +
      "</span></p>";
    $("#text").val("");
    $(".msg-page").append(userHtml);

    $.ajax({
      data: {
        msg: rawText,
      },
      type: "POST",
      url: "/get",
    }).done(function (data) {
      var botHtml =
        '<p class="outgoing-chats-msg" ><span class="outgoing-chats-msg-p" >' +
        data +
        "</span></p>";
      $(".msg-page").append($.parseHTML(botHtml));
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

I have tried CSS styles such as overflow-wrap but didn't work. I expect the response to be under a single field broken into different line depending on the text length.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Can you please provide a minimal example to replicate this issue probably a https://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: FYI, the code you've posted is **wide open** to XSS attacks.  Because you are concatenating/interpolating text directly into the context of HTML, anyone can inject scripts and what not right into your page.  Not only is this a security problem, but it will also start to break your page anytime someone types a reserved character like `<` or `"`.  At a minimum, you should be setting `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`.  But, you might find it easier to just use a template setup, like with Lit.

Answer (score 1):

The script that you shared has nothing to do with the issue. The problem is with the CSS. Since you've not shared the CSS, and from the image it can be seen that the text is not wrapping properly when the it reaches it's max width. I've recreated your situation and tried to provide a fix.

The problem from my perspective is- you're probably not using ***[`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)*** or `word-wrap` peroperty. You need to apply the below CSS to achieve the expected result.

```css
.received-msg-inbox-p, .outgoing-chats-msg-p {
  white-space: pre-wrap;      /* CSS3 */
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */
  white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera <7 */
  white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */
  word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE */
}
```

**Implementation:**

```css
.chat-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 600px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.chat-message {
  max-width: 80%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.other-person {
  align-self: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.you {
  align-self: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background-color: #0b93f6;
  color: white;
}

.chat-message p {
  margin: 0;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
  white-space: -pre-wrap;
  white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat-container">
  <div class="chat-message other-person">
    <p>Hello! This is a long message from another person in the chat. It should wrap onto the next line if it's too long for the chat bubble.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="chat-message you">
    <p>Hi! This is a long message from you in the chat. It should also wrap onto the next line if it's too long for the chat bubble.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.